# View logic in the Model

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller

I have a Model like this:

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :size
end
```

Now i want to display the size in a human readable format. I could do this by adding the following code:

```
class MyModel

  attr_accessor :size

  def size_hr(bytes = nil, counter = -1)
    counter += 1
    bytes ||= size
    if bytes < 1024
      return "#{bytes.round(2)} #{unit_for(counter)}"
    else
      size_hr bytes/1024, counter
    end
  end

  def unit_for(counter)
    case counter
    when 0 then "B"
    when 1 then "KiB"
    when 2 then "MiB"
    when 3 then "GiB"
    end
  end
end
```

But I feel somehow bad about this as I would mix view stuff into the model. I'm looking for a design pattern which would be the right approach to do this. I read about decorator and presenter, but I don't think they fit in here. What would be the right approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rails View Helpers, which is the simple and straight forward way. IMHO the Helpers tend to end up as junk drawer for all sorts of things. Thus, we prefer do work with the [Deocrator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). A good gem to do this would be [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/drape).

Comment: The railscast gives a pretty good overview. I personally hate helpers and feel like it's a huge area for improvement in Rails. http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of a *Helper Class* in rails.

Helper classes are also sometimes called *View Helpers* for this reason.

In the file `/app/helpers/my_model_helper.rb`, you'd define this module (that rails automatically mixes in).

```
module MyModelHelper

  def size_hr(@my_model, counter = -1)
    counter += 1
    bytes = @my_model.size
    if bytes < 1024
      return "#{bytes.round(2)} #{unit_for(counter)}"
    else
      size_hr bytes/1024, counter
    end
  end

  def unit_for(counter)
    case counter
    when 0 then "B"
    when 1 then "KiB"
    when 2 then "MiB"
    when 3 then "GiB"
    end
  end

end
```

Then in your view you'd simply call that method like so:

```
size_hr(@myModel)
```

Views also have the advantage of being [relatively easy to write unit tests for](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec).

Comment: Yeah, this is where my code already resides. But I don't feel well with this. Isn't this something which should be more specific to the model?

Comment: This is a gray area in general. It depends on the data the method is returning. If you believe the data returned should be considered an *attribute* of the model (like age, date of birth, size, etc) then I think it's best to include it in the model. Otherwise put it in the view helper and feel good that it's in the right place.